# music21 format stream as ABC+ and save as a file

Tags: xml, language-agnostic, music21, musicxml, abc-notation

I have some music in the MusicXML format (`.mxl` files). How can I convert these files to ABC notation (`.abc` files)? Can music21 do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`music21` does not currently have the ability to export abc, only import.

Answer (score 1):

You could hack something with node and xml2abc. Mxl is musicxml in a zip file.

Here is a code snippet i use in zupfnoter; It

```js
function pasteXml(text){
                        try{
                          var xmldata = $.parseXML(text);
                         }
                        catch(ex){
                          #{$log.error(`ex.message`)}
                        }

                        var options = {
                                'u': 0, 'b': 0, 'n': 0,    // unfold repeats (1), bars per line, chars per line
                        'c': 0, 'v': 0, 'd': 0,    // credit text filter level (0-6), no volta on higher voice numbers (1), denominator unit length (L:)
                        'm': 0, 'x': 0,           // with midi volume and panning (1), no line breaks (1)
                        'p': 'f'
                      };              // page format: scale (1.0), width, left- and right margin in cm

                      result = vertaal(xmldata, options);
                      return result;
}

function pasteMxl(text){
   zip = new JSZip(text);
   text = zip.file(/^[^/ ]*\.xml$/)[0].asText();
   pasteXml(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this web service instead? http://www.mandolintab.net/abcconverter.php

Comment: thanks! but i need a automated stack solution where i can process a bunch of mxl files.